# (PHP) string variable as an if expression (string $other_variable names too)

Tags: php, string, if-statement, expression, eval

So I have this chunk of code:

```
$age = 23;
    $gender = 0;

    $rules = "gender = 0 AND ( age >= 2 AND age <= 20 )";
    $find = array(
      ' = ',
      'age',
      'gender'
    );
    $replace = array(
      ' === ',
      '$age',
      '$gender'
    );
    $rules = str_replace($find, $replace, $rules);
    print($rules);
    if (eval('return' . $rules . ';')) {
      return "You get coupon " . $coupon->couponID . "!";
    } else {
      return "Coupon " . $coupon->couponID . " is not for you!";
    }
```

What I am trying to do is used that string variable as my if expression. Is this possible? Or is there a better way to achieved this?

Comment: What about `if($rules)` ?

Comment: that was in my original code. it doesnt work. always returns true. :(

Comment: @arkascha - That will always return `true` as `$rules` is not `false` or `null`.

Comment: @RhanCandia what do you want to check by the `if` statement? Do you want to check whether the `$rules` string has been changed because of the replacement?

Comment: @chayasan the rules are being fetched from the database. those are generated by a querybuilder.  after that `str_replace`. the `$rules` will become `$rules = "$gender === 0 AND ( $age >= 2 AND $age <= 20 )";` the `$age` and `$gender` in the code will be the values.

Comment: Okay I see.! But with `if` condition what do you want to check?

Comment: @chayasan i want to check if the expression is true or false.

Comment: Ah yes, This way you can achieve what you want. It will be much clear, if you can do the `replace`, and `eval` logic inside a separate function and call it inside `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. The problem was with `===` as comparison. When I used `==` instead, it worked!

Here's the code now.

```
$rules = "$age >= 2 AND $age <= 20 AND ( $gender = 1 OR $gender = 2 )";
    $find = array(
      ' = ',
      'age',
      'gender'
    );
    $replace = array(
      ' == ',
      '$age',
      '$gender'
    );
    $rules = str_replace($find, $replace, $rules);
    print($rules);
    if (eval(sprintf('return (%s);', $rules))) {
      return "You get coupon " . $coupon->couponID . "!";
    } else {
      return "Coupon " . $coupon->couponID . " is not for you!";
    }
```